# Unable to find a place to inject the manifest

Tags: laravel, workbox

I am trying to make my laravel a PWA. What I did is,
run

> npm install workbox-cli -g

create sw-base.js file in public folder,

```
importScripts(
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.0.2/workbox-sw.js'
);

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);
```

Now created a  workbox-config.js file at the root folder,

```
module.exports = {
    globDirectory: 'public/',
    globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css,png,jpg}','offline.html'],
    swSrc: 'public/sw-base.js',
    swDest: 'public/service-worker.js',
    globIgnores: [
        '../workbox-cli-config.js',
        'photos/**'
  ]
};
```

added scripts in package.json

> "generate-sw": "workbox injectManifest workbox-config.js"

Now When running

> npm run generate-sw

I get error like

> Service worker generation failed:
> Unable to find a place to inject the manifest. Please ensure that your service worker file contains the following: self.__WB_MANIFEST

I followed [this](https://shareurcodes.com/blog/how-to-easily-convert-your-existing-laravel-application-into-a-progressive-web-app-by-using-workbox) tutorial, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use InjectManifest you should have an existing service worker.
I would reccomend use GenerateSW. It will create the service worker for you.

Comment: Thanks. Where to add that code, please give a link to documentation for laravel.

Comment: I followed [this](https://shareurcodes.com/blog/how-to-easily-convert-your-existing-laravel-application-into-a-progressive-web-app-by-using-workbox) tutorial, but not working.

Comment: I added workbox generateSW in script, now I get configuration invalid, ```module.exports = {
    globDirectory: 'public/',
    globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css,png,jpg}','offline.html'],
    swSrc: 'public/sw-base.js',
    swDest: 'public/service-worker.js',
    globIgnores: [
        '../workbox-cli-config.js',
        'photos/**'
  ]
};```